# Android Studio -> Invalid File location for slice_3.apk file

Tags: android-studio

I just swapped my Harddrive so I had to move my Android Studio Project Folder from E: ... \Documents to C: ... \Desktop

Now when I try to run my App I will receive this error:

> Installation failed with message Invalid File: E:\Bibliotheken\Tim\Dokumente\Android Studio\LearningUnit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

So I wonder where I have to change the path for this file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Steps to Resolve

Inside Android Studio first

1. Go to `Build --> Clean Project`

Then

2. Goto `Build --> Build Apk`

Try again to run the app, it should now succeed.